# Playing sounds in WPF as a resource

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, resources

First of all, I've searched the site and looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145209/how-to-play-a-wpf-sound-file-resource) but unfortunately it did not help me much.

Whenever I click a frog image that I made, I want to play a .wav file as a resource. Here's my code:

```
void newFrog_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"G:\COSR3S\FrogsAndLilyPads\FrogsAndLilyPads\Sounds\FrogCroak.wav");
    player.Play();
}
```

Of course this worked but my problem is the directory changes from computer to computer, so I thought I'd have to play it as a resource. I don't know how to do that. I am a fairly new programmer, just to keep in mind.

I tried a few variations based on the aforementioned [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145209/how-to-play-a-wpf-sound-file-resource) and played around with it. Examples:

```
void newFrog_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Sounds/FrogCroak.wav");
    var player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.Open(uri);
    player.Play();
}
```

I also tried doing this, although I thought this one wouldn't work, but I tried it anyway:

```
void newFrog_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Sounds/FrogCroak.wav");
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(uri);
    player.Play();
}
```

I was not sure if the "`pack://application:,,,`" was something that would refer to the file being played.

I also tried to make it as if it was an image, like so:

```
void newFrog_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Sounds/FrogCroak.wav", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    player.Play();
}
```

So instead of `new BitmapImage` I did `new System.Media.SoundPlayer` and only to find out that it wouldn't work that way.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this worked, but it did not play any sound.

```
void newFrog_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Sounds/FrogCroak.wav");
    var player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.Open(uri);
    player.Play();
}
```

Edit2: The possible duplicate technically didn't solve my problem, but according to the accepted answer it is not possible. Is there any other way I could play the audio using a different method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me using Visual Studio 2013 with a command line application:

- Embed the .wav file as a resource (Resources.resx) in the project

  - I used Add Resource from Existing file
  - Set the persistence for the file as 'Linked at compile time'
- Reference the file from code using something like this. Timer is the namespace this code is from and NotificationSound is what I called the embedded sound:

  ```
  var notificationSound = new SoundPlayer(Timer.Properties.Resources.NotificationSound);
  notificationSound.PlaySync();
  ```

This allowed me to play the sound from the application after moving the executable and renaming the original sound file (just to check that it was actually embedded).

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but would this work in Visual Studio 2010 because that is the version my school is using.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio 2010 to test with but I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work. The instructions just might be a little different.